# I do not understand how we can use method compareTo inside a method compareTo

Tags: java, oop

I am doing this project where I would get some number of books and I should sort it ,following this logic:

1. If a book has more pages than the other, then the book with the more pages goes first.
2. If both books have the same number of pages, then sort by the title alphabetically.
3. If both books have the same number of pages and the same title, then sort by the author alphabetically.

I tried to solve but did not manage to, so I looked up in the solution:

```
public class Book implements Comparable<Book>{

   public int compareTo(Book specifiedBook) {
      // First check if they have different page counts

      if(this.numberOfPages != specifiedBook.numberOfPages){

         // this will return a negative value if this < specified but will return a positive value if this > specified
         return this.numberOfPages - specifiedBook.numberOfPages;
      }

      // If page counts are identical then check if the titles are different
      if(!this.title.equals(specifiedBook.title){

         return this.title.compareTo(specifiedBook.title);
      }

      // If page titles are also identical then return the comparison of the authors

      return this.author.compareTo(specifiedBook.author);
    }
}
```

What I do not understand here is this part 'return this.title.compareTo(specifiedBook.title);'. How can we use method compareTo inside a method compareTo , wouldn't it that be a recursion, I Know that as we implemented the interface comperable we must override the method compareTo, but how can we use that compareTo method inside the Overriden compareTo method? And what should it do, in this case and in general?

What confuses me, is how can we use the method that is just declared in interface, it is not inherited from the parent class. It is just declared in the comparable interface so when we implement the interface we must override it

Comment: the method is being called on different instances, which for sure are not calling `compareTo` from the actual instance - so not recursive - this often happens with the `toString` method, where one object calls `toString` of its component to create its own result for `toString`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `title` and `author` are strings, you're calling `String.compareTo` (which is already implemented), from inside `Book.compareTo`. It's not recursion. It's a method in a different class.

Comment: You mean inside class String, there is a (overriden) method compareTo, and because of that I can use that when comparing two Strings?

Comment: @Petar Yes the `String` class has a `compareTo` method that allows you to compare two strings.

Answer (score -1):

The most easiest and better way to use java.util.Comparator for comparing fields. I would highly recommend to override equals and hashCode method since you are going to put the books in some container which might be a Sorted Set or something like that. Anyway, here is the example code,

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class BookTest {

  @Test
  public void compareBooks() {
    Book b1 = new Book(100, "A book", "Zoro");
    Book b2 = new Book(10, "Small book", "ABC");
    TreeSet<Book> books = new TreeSet<>();
    books.add(b1);
    books.add(b2);
    System.out.println(books);
  }

  private class Book implements Comparable<Book> {
    private final int numberOfPages;
    private final String title;
    private final String author;

    private Book(int numberOfPages, String title, String author) {
      this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
      this.title = title;
      this.author = author;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPages() {
      return numberOfPages;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
      return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
      return author;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Book that) {
      return Comparator.nullsFirst(
              Comparator.comparing(Book::getNumberOfPages)
                  .thenComparing(Book::getTitle)
                  .thenComparing(Book::getAuthor))
          .compare(this, that);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
      Book book = (Book) o;
      return numberOfPages == book.numberOfPages
          && title.equals(book.title)
          && author.equals(book.author);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(numberOfPages, title, author);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return new StringJoiner(", ", Book.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
          .add("numberOfPages=" + numberOfPages)
          .add("title='" + title + "'")
          .add("author='" + author + "'")
          .toString();
    }
  }
}
```